# How do I execute a tezos-client transfer programmatically?

Tags: tezos-client, transfer, programmatically, linux, shell

Is it possible to call a tezos-client binary from within a programming language? I have been trying to achieve this, but without success. The very same command used through the command line works, but when I call it from a script, it fails.

I've seen some advice to write the command inside a shell script, like test.sh. I did this and the script only works in the command line. If I call it from within a program, it fails too.

Is this a security measure of tezos-client? Or is there a correct way to do it?

This is the command I want to call in my software:

```
tezos-client transfer 1 from myAlias to tz1.... --fee 0.05 --dry-run
```

Comment: Please report the error message you say otherwise it is unclear what is your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to be as explicit as possible:

- specify the full path to `tezos-client`
- specify the absolute directory containing the data, especially the aliases (generally `--base-dir /home/[..USER..]/.tezos-client`)

If it does not work, copy-paste the error messages, so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: This solved the problem. After I've added --base-dir /home/user/tezos/.tezos-client to the transfer command, it worked flawlessly. A sample functional command would be like this: /home/user/tezos/tezos-client --base-dir /home/user/.tezos-client transfer 1 from myAlias to tz1.... --fee 0.05 --dry-run

Answer (score 1):

Try the full path. Like that:

```
home/your_user_name/tezos/tezos-client transfer 1 from myAlias to tz1.... --fee 0.05 --dry-run
```

Comment: I've already tried full path and there is no difference. It works on cmd line, but fails if called inside a program.  Tezos-client returns a message saying it does not recognize the alias.

Comment: Check the user your script is running as. It sounds like it may not be the one you think it is.

Comment: The full path is important, but what was really missing was the --base-dir parameter. Anyways, thank you a lot.